# Django: each paginated page shows the same results

Tags: django, pagination, django-urls

So I am trying to use pagination to display all the matching classes available on a certain day, but following the pagination docs, each page just returns the same 10 results.  What am I missing/ what should I have in urlconf? Additionally, if I try using pagination to display search results, I get the error "The view search.views.search_classes didn't return an HttpResponse object" when I try to select the next page.  Any input into either or both examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
#views.py
def upcoming_class_list(request, day):
    try:
        day = int(day)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    today = datetime.date.today()
    day_x = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=day)
    day_x_classes = UpcomingClasses.objects.filter(class_date=day_x)
    all_matches = day_x_classes
    paginator = Paginator(all_matches, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        matches = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        matches = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        matches = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('preview.html', {'today': today, 'tomorrow': tomorrow,
            'past_classes': past_classes, 'day_x': day_x, 'day': day,
            'day_x_classes': day_x_classes, 'yesterday': yesterday, 'matches': matches,
            'page': page}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

#urls.py
(r'^upcoming_class_list/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', upcoming_class_list),

#preview.html
<h3>Classes for {{ day_x }}</h3>
{% if matches %}
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if matches.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ matches.previous_page_number }}">&laquo; previous </a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
            Page {{ matches.number }} of {{ matches.paginator.num_pages }} 
            </span>

            {% if matches.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ matches.next_page_number }}"> next &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

    {% if day_x_classes %}
        <ul type=none>
        {% for class in day_x_classes %}
            <li>
                <ul type=none>
                    <li><strong>{{ class.type }}</strong></li>
                    <li>Teacher: <a href="/profiles/{{ class.teacher }}">{{ class.teacher }}</a></li>
                    <li>Class Description: {{ class.description }}</li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </li><br />
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
<p>There are currently no scheduled upcoming classes for {{ day_x }}.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out the answer to both of my questions.  The first part was because I was making a dumb mistake in my template.  The view urlconf were correct, but in my template, my for loop stated:

```
{% for class in day_x_classes %}
```

when I should have been using

```
{% for class in matches %}
```

since matches was being paginated, not day_x_classes.
As far as paginating my search results, I simply needed to edit the "previous" and "next" buttons from

```
<a href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ matches.previous_page_number }}">&laquo; previous </a>
```

from

```
<a href="?page={{ matches.previous_page_number }}">&laquo; previous</a>
```

to account for q (the searched term).

I hope that my mistakes will be able to help someone who was stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Anything coming from GET or POST will be a string, so you're always hitting that first exception. Try:

```
try:
    matches = paginator.page(int(page))
except (PageNotAnInteger, ValueError):
    matches = paginator.page(1)
```

It's hard to guess at the rest of the issue without seeing the rest of your view. Looking at other bits in the view, you shouldn't need the check for day being an int as you've already assured that in your urls.py file with the regex, but you [don't call the Http404 object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception), it's simply `raise Http404`

Comment: the rest of my view is just... return render_to_response('preview.html', {'today': today, 'tomorrow': tomorrow, 'past_classes': past_classes, 'day_x': day_x, 'day': day, 'day_x_classes': day_x_classes, 'yesterday': yesterday, 'matches': matches, 'page': page}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))    ...If I try matches = paginator.page(int(page)) I get the TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: `paginator.page('1')` works fine. Django casts to int internally.

Comment: Additionally, I have determined that all of my matching results are showing up on every page.  For example, I have paginator=Paginator(all_matches, 10), however, all 11 results will show up on the first page.  I am using Django 1.4, and I am essentially following the documentation exactly, at least as far as I can tell, unless I'm missing something.